# What would be the flow rate of 5 L hydrogen at 20 bar being vented through a 1/4 inch (assumed smooth) stainless steel pipeline to standard pressure?

Tags: fluid, compressible-flow

As the title says, I have a 1 m pipe network of 1/4 inch diameter connected to a 5 L bottle of 20 bar hydrogen. If this system was to open suddenly, what would be the volumetric flow rate out the other end of the 1 m pipe in m3/s?

Secondly, would it make a difference if the end of the pipe opened into a 3/8 inch pipe or can we assume the flow rate is the same?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the hydrogen gas is incompressible, the perforation factor is 1, and the friction loss in the pipe is insignificant, we measure the discharge volume at the connection of the pipe to the tank.

Assuming that the density of hydrogen gas is 0.0899 kg/m<sup>3</sup> at standard temperature and pressure (STP), the cross-sectional area of a 1/4 inch diameter pipe is 4.91x10<sup>-5</sup> m<sup>2</sup>, and the pressure at the exit of the pipe is 20 bar, we can calculate the velocity of the gas at the exit of the pipe:

- $\rho$ is density
- P    pressure
- u    speed of gas

$$P=\frac{1}{2}\ \rho u^2$$

$$2(20)/\rho=u^2$$
$$u =\sqrt{(40*10^5Pa/0.0899)}= 924.6m/s$$

and finally the volumetric instantaneus inital (the pressure decreases as the gas scapes) flow rate is

$$ Q = AV = (π/4)(0.25*0.0254 m)^2 * 924.6 m/s = 1.14 m^3/s $$

It doesn't make much difference if the end of the pipe is 3/8 inch.

Comment: Thanks so much! If we were to say that the gas is compressible (because realistically hydrogen is), would you expect the flow to increase or decrease?

Comment: decrease, it would vibrate and pant and be very turbulent. before the perforation and in the pipe. it will make it choke, in reality, it is compressible because probably its speed is close to the speed of sound in hydrogen!

Comment: Thanks for your clarification Kamran!